# Select a specific python version for CPLEX installation (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, installation, cplex

I'd like to install [IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.9.0](https://www.ibm.com/it-it/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio) (by double-clicking on its ".exe" executable file) on my PC which runs `Windows 10`.

In this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html) there's a brief installation guide, which says:

"The modules associated with the CPLEX Python API reside in the directory **yourCPLEXhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM**, (or in the folder yourCPLEXhome\python\VERSION\PLATFORM) where:

- yourCPLEXhome: specifies the location where CPLEX is installed as part of IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio;
- VERSION: designates a version of Python compatible with CPLEX;
- PLATFORM: stands for your combination of operating system and compiler."

On my PC reside two different Python versions: `3.5.9` and `3.7.3`, respectively.

I want that CPLEX will work only with Python **3.5.9**; in other words, I want that the field `VERSION` in **yourCPLEXhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM** will be `3.5.9`, and not `3.7.3`.

So, how could I choose a specific Python version to use with CPLEX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer will always install both versions. Which one is actually use depends on which of the two you activate by running `setup.py` or to which you point `PYTHONPATH`.